# Como encontrar arquivos com conflito no GIT?

Tags: git

Imaginemos que eu acabei de fazer um `git pull`. Daí, por algum movito eu fechei o `Terminal` (No `Ubuntu`, por exemplo) e não vi quais são os arquivos marcados como `CONFLICT`.

Eu já aprendi de uma maneira onde eu executaria o comando `grep` no diretório do repositório local.

Exemplo:

```
> grep -Hrs "<<< HEAD" .
```

Como eu posso fazer (de outra maneira) para descobrir quais são arquivos com conflito?

Existe alguma maneira de se fazer isso pelo próprio `GIT`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10874862/664577) basta usar:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
```

Comment: Realmente, funcionou! Queria saber pra que serve esse `diff`?

Comment: Para ver as diferenças entre duas versões quaisquer. Se você digitar apenas `git diff` ele mostra todas as diferenças entre o diretório corrente e o índice, mas dá para fazer muito mais (vale uma outra pergunta)