# Pra que serve o comando git diff?

Tags: git

[Fiz essa pergunta a pouco tempo aqui no SOPT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76069/como-encontrar-arquivos-com-conflito-no-git).

Surgiram algumas dúvidas, e então o usuário [@AnthonyAccioly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/100/anthony-accioly) me recomendeu fazer essa pergunta.

Para que serve o comando `git diff`?

Comment: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`diff` serve para verificar diferenças entre commits, arquivos e árvores de diretórios](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

## Exemplos:

- `git diff`: Exibe todas as diferenças entre sua cópia local e o índice sincronizado;
- `git diff –cached`: Exibe todas as diferenças entre o índice sincronizado e o último *commit*;
- `git diff HEAD`: Exibe todas as diferenças entre sua cópia local e o último *commit* realizado;

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente, o comando `git diff` serve para mostrar as diferenças entre arquivos.

[Como exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25931860/2387977), veja uma saída deste comando, mostrando as alteração no `arquivo`:

```
diff --git a/arquivo b/arquivo
index 10ff2df..84d4fa2 100644
--- a/arquivo
+++ b/arquivo
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 linha1
 linha2
-esta linha foi removida
 linha4
 linha5
+esta linha foi adicionada
```

Ele pode ser usado tanto para mostrar as diferenças entre arquivos *not staged* (arquivos comitados que tiveram alguma alteração):

```
git diff
```

Ou de arquivos *staged* e *not staged* (além dos arquivos citados anteriormente, também mostra as alterações de arquivos adicionados com `git add`):

```
git diff HEAD
```

Ou mesmo entre commits:

```
git diff b4cb8d9..9c5733f
```

Creio que os comandos acima sejam as formas mais comuns de usar o `diff`. Como o comando é bem flexível e tem várias opções de uso, sugiro dar uma olhada na [documentação oficial](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).